# Consumer Producer doesn't work in java

Tags: java, synchronization

I tried to create a consumer producer according to the offical oracle example (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/guardmeth.html).

This solution creates a problem for me beacuse somehow consume (or produce) are executed twice.

example output:

**0.27621192120612414**

**0.24838246527492802, 0.30404137713732027**

**0.8848100139189661**

**0.9910138279470992, 0.778606199890833**

**0.17368370874476935, 0.5661899414440023**
.......

My code is very similar to the one oracle posted:

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Consumer implements Runnable {

    private SharedData sharedData;

    public Consumer(SharedData sharedData) {
    this.sharedData = sharedData;
    }

    @
    Override
    public void run() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

        double result = this.sharedData.calc();
        System.out.println(result);

        try {
        Thread.sleep(20);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    }

public class Producer implements Runnable {

    private SharedData sharedData;

    private Random numGenerator = new Random();

    public Producer(SharedData sharedData) {
        this.sharedData = sharedData;
    }

    @
    Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        double firstNum = numGenerator.nextDouble();
        double secondNum = numGenerator.nextDouble();

        this.sharedData.store(firstNum, secondNum);
        System.out.println(firstNum + ", " + secondNum);

        try {
            Thread.sleep(20);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        }
    }
}

public class SharedData {

    private double x = 0;
    private double y = 0;

    private boolean empty = true;

    public synchronized double calc() {
        while (empty) {
        try {
            wait();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
        }
        empty = true;
        notifyAll();
        return (x + y) / 2;
    }

    public synchronized void store(double x, double y) {
        while (!empty) {
        try {
            wait();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
        }
        // Toggle status.
        empty = false;
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        notifyAll();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you are seeing is not a failure of the guarding system, it is a failure in your printing mechanism.

Here's an example you could use. I have created a new class called `Calc` which holds the details of the calculation at the time it was calculated. It shows the system works fine:

```
public class Consumer implements Runnable {

    private SharedData sharedData;

    public Consumer(SharedData sharedData) {
        this.sharedData = sharedData;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

            Calc result = this.sharedData.calc();
            System.out.println(result);

            try {
                Thread.sleep(20);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

}

public class Producer implements Runnable {

    private SharedData sharedData;

    private Random numGenerator = new Random();

    public Producer(SharedData sharedData) {
        this.sharedData = sharedData;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            double firstNum = numGenerator.nextDouble();
            double secondNum = numGenerator.nextDouble();

            this.sharedData.store(firstNum, secondNum);
            //System.out.println("Sum: " + firstNum + ", " + secondNum);

            try {
                Thread.sleep(20);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }

}

public class Calc {

    final double x;
    final double y;
    final double r;

    public Calc(double x, double y, double r) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.r = r;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return x + "," + y + "=" + r;
    }
}

public class SharedData {

    private double x = 0;
    private double y = 0;

    private volatile boolean empty = true;

    public synchronized Calc calc() {
        while (empty) {
            try {
                wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }
        }
        // Create my Calc before the data can be changed.
        Calc calc = new Calc(x, y, (x + y) / 2);
        empty = true;
        notifyAll();
        return calc;
    }

    public synchronized void store(double x, double y) {
        while (!empty) {
            try {
                wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }
        }
        // Toggle status.
        empty = false;
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        notifyAll();
    }

}

public void test() throws InterruptedException {
    System.out.println("Hello");
    SharedData data = new SharedData();
    Thread pThread = new Thread(new Producer(data));
    Thread cThread = new Thread(new Consumer(data));
    pThread.start();
    cThread.start();
    pThread.join();
    cThread.join();
}
```

I get:

```
0.6724169142503265,0.6079999474086301=0.6402084308294782
0.6821043385454105,0.08553214712777224=0.3838182428365914
0.9527912599940244,0.4659048372170267=0.7093480486055255
0.23726296551963733,0.09811671486141438=0.16768984019052585
0.192398049915115,0.7641124370868287=0.47825524350097187
0.014149497154971824,0.07331728450626529=0.04373339083061856
0.7143483172261206,0.532969217817149=0.6236587675216347
0.3660578187157878,0.5246494194965169=0.44535361910615234
0.8368831236536345,0.9004030373411539=0.8686430804973941
0.6986966105042433,0.4459182041312596=0.5723074073177514
```

which adds up fine as far as I can see.

Note - however - that once you set `empty` to `true` in `calc` the other thread can modify `x` and `y`. You should really do the calculation **before** you set the `empty` flag.

Also note that your `empty` flag should be `volatile`.

Answer (score 1):

Your `System.out.println` calls are not in any synchronized section, so even if the producer has produced before the consumer has consumed, nothing guarantees that its output will come before the consumer output:

1. producer thread produces, consumer thread waits
2. consumer thread consumes
3. consumer thread prints result
4. producer thread prints result

Put the `System.out.println` calls inside the synchronized sections, and you should see a strict alternance between consumer and producer output.

Comment: But you can see the offical oracle gaurded blocks (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/guardmeth.html) do the same thing with the System.out.println. Will their code have the same problem?